# Convert Webp to PDF

Tags: pdf, ffmpeg, conversion, gnu-parallel, webp

I want to convert a bunch of Webp images to individual PDFs. I'm able to do it with this command:

`parallel convert '{} {.}.pdf' ::: *.webp`

or I can use this FFMPEG command:

`find ./ -name "*.webp" -exec dwebp {} -o {}.pdf \;`

However during the process of conversion the Webp files are decoded and the resultant PDFs have a much bigger file size. When I use the above commands for JPG-to-PDF conversion the PDF size is reasonably close to the JPG image size.

This command works fine with JPGs, but the program img2pdf doesn't work with the Webp format:

```
find ./ -name "*.jpg" -exec img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf \;
```

I also tried Webp-to-PDF conversion with [this online service](https://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf), but the PDF was huge.

How can I keep the PDF size down to the Webp file size?

Comment: One possibility is to first convert the webp images to jpg, then to pdf. This might reduce the quality a little, but should work.

Comment: Yes this would work, but I am specifically asking how to do this with webp files.

Comment: You will only get a small size pdf if you go via an intermediate jpg stage, as jpg compression is supported natively in pdf, but webp is not.

Comment: Could I get webp compression supported in pdf through some other program?

Comment: Yeah, I guess until pdf supports webp natively (or someone writes a PS implementation of the webp decode in a way small enough to include in a PDF!) this won't be possible without losing significant quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use Imagemagick and Ghostscript?

```
convert img.webp img.pdf
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile=img-small.pdf img.pdf
```

In my test with your sample file I got a pdf result of about 3.2 MB.

EDIT

You could [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251950/imagemagick-convert-cant-convert-to-webp#251954) on **Ubuntu** to make sure that imagemagick was built with webp. Install this package [for Windows](https://github.com/ImageMagick/web%20for%20Windows) or on **macos** do this:

```
brew install webp
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: I have ImageMagick already and have tried some commands. Your command takes a series of webp images that amount to 2mb and creates a 100mb pdf. Even when I reduce the quality to 80 and the density to 50x50. I want a command that will give me a pdf that is roughly equal in size to the source webp images.

Comment: @user8547 can you post a link to webp file example you are working on?

Comment: Here's a link. When I try all the methods of converting this to pdf it comes out around 150mb. https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/H3e1vmd.webp

Comment: @user8547 updated with working sample script.

Comment: I have ImageMagick 64 bit on Windows 10, so I needed to use `magick` instead of `convert` as a command. With the Ghostscript command `"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/eBook  -sOutputFile=imgsmall.pdf img.pdf` i get the error `Unrecoverable error: undefined in get Operand stack: --nostringval--  eBook`

Comment: I tried your command first on the Ubuntu Subsystem for Windows, but had no luck getting it to work. I got this long error: `Unknown device: pdfwrite-dNOPAUSE
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1088: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc
| ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1708: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
Unrecoverable error: unknownerror in .special_op
Operand stack:  defaultdevice
Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
Operand stack:  defaultdevice`

Comment: My bad - autocorrect bit again, it should be ebook without the camel case. I updated the answer for you